# __android_log_print not printing from library

Tags: android, c++, logging, android-ndk

I have a NDK application which is made up of three parts (shared libraries):

- A base library which among other things has some logging functions, these call __android_log_print
- My game engine library, this calls logging functions from the base library
- The main module, this calls logging functions from the base library, and functions from the game engine that would generate log output

Everything compiles and runs successfully, but I see no log output at all even when I know that __android_log_print is being called (I put an assertion in on the line to cause it to abort to make sure).

If I call __android_log_print from the main module directly, it works. If I call logging statements from the Java shim activity, it also works, but calling through my library prints nothing.

What would cause this? Is there something in Android that prevents logging from library code?

**EDIT: It looks like __android_log_print is somehow being redirected to stdout/stderr - I have no idea how that's possible? I'm using SDL2 if it's relevant**

Comment: Are you sure nothing is redefining __android_log_print in the game engine library?  Use `arm-eabi-nm -D` to verify that it appears as an unresolved symbol in the library .so.

Comment: Actually, there may be some extra logic in the _base library_ that would redefine behavior of logging operations. My library, for example, reads a configuration file to decide whether to use logcat or a log file, and also chooses the debug level. Do you have source code for this library, or only compiled form?

Answer (score 0):

Hah! So it turns out that due to a remarkable set of blunders involving a symlink, an old header file and a coincidental crash that I rashly thought was my assertion, I wasn't even calling __android_log_print!

My game engine was picking up an old header file, in which was an inline implementation of the logging code (which has since been moved into a source file). This was then being compiled into the game engine library, thus the proper implementation in the base library was ignored.

I'd never have figured this out if I hadn't started looking for unresolved symbols in the game engine library, so thanks for that fadden! :)